# Format DateTime without converting it to String

Tags: c#, datetime, ebay-api

I have a `GetOrders` class that required me to supply the start and end dates as the `DateTime` values.  Nevertheless, when I supply the dates, I am getting this error message: `Sorry, the end date was missing, invalid, or before the start date. <EndDate> must be in YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS format, and after the start date.`

This is my code:

`ff.GetOrders(DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-1), TradingRoleCodeType.Buyer, OrderStatusCodeType.Completed);`

When I try to use formatted string, it does **not** work:

```
        String dt1 = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
        String dt2 = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
```

Comment: Try not converting it to UTC, send the default `DateTime.Now`

Comment: It appears that you are setting the end date to be 1 month *earlier* than the start date?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming GetOrders has startdate,enddate (which I can't tell because you didn't give the function prototype for GetOrders), then your dates are in the wrong order or you should AddMonths(1) instead of -1.

(If this isn't the case, please include the function proto for GetOrders and I will revise or delete my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

As noted, your maths are a little...off, I think:

```
ff.GetOrders( DateTime.UtcNow               ,
              DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-1) ,
              TradingRoleCodeType.Buyer     ,
              OrderStatusCodeType.Completed
            ) ;
```

Try something like

```
DateTime dtStart = DateTime.utcNow      ;
DateTime dtEnd   = dtStart.AddMonths(1) ;

ff.GetOrders( dtStart ,
              dtEnd   ,
              TradingRoleCodeType.Buyer ,
              OrderStatuscodeType.Completed
            ) ;
```

As a general practice, keeping individual computations separate rather than combining them in a method call makes the code easier to understand, easier to modify and easier to debug.